# Using shell command sending mail in Perl is not working

Tags: perl

I'm trying to send an email using Perl script, by using shell command. It is not giving any error and not sending email.

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl
        my $mail_command="echo hello | mail -s hi -r 'x@zz.com' 'y@zz.com'";
            print($mail_command);
            qx($mail_command);
```

When I print the message it shows like this.

```
    echo hello | mail -s hi -r 'x.com' 'y.com'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is variable interpolation; however you still need quotes around your email addresses. Try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my $mail_command=q(echo hello | mail -s hi -r 'x@zz.com' 'y@zz.com');
print($mail_command);
qx($mail_command);
```

`q()` acts like single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't send mail using command-line programs like that. There are many good mail modules on CPAN. Please take a look at [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) or [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).